# CMake add_custom_command OUTPUT support for build/configuration type

Tags: cmake

I want `add_custom_command()` to produce a different output depending on whether I'm building for Debug or Release (with a support for Visual Studio multi-configuration builds).

Essentially, I want to achieve something like:

```
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT $<IF:$<CONFIG:Debug>, file_to_generate_in_debug, file_to_generate_in_release>
    COMMAND something.exe
    ...
)
```

Unfortunately, the generator expressions are not supported for the OUTPUT argument.

How should I do it using Modern CMake?

---

To make it more concrete, I'm trying to run `windeployqt.exe` to and my output should be either `Qt5Core.dll` or `Qt5Cored.dll` depending on the actual build configuration (which could either be known at Configure-time (e.g. for Ninja) or at Generate-time (e.g. for Visual Studio)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create as many `add_custom_command` as different *OUTPUT* you need to produce.

```
# A command which can be applied for Debug configuration(s)
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT file_to_generate_in_debug
    COMMAND something.exe
    ...
)
# A command which can be applied for Release configuration(s)
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT file_to_generate_in_release
    COMMAND something.exe
    ...
)
```

Only that instance will be active in a specific configuration which *OUTPUT* is used as *DEPENDS* in (other) `add_custom_command`/`add_custom_target`. Unlike to *OUTPUT*, *DEPENDS* clause supports generator expressions.

```
# This will chose a command suitable for configuration
add_custom_target(MY_GEN_LIB
   DEPENDS $<IF:$<CONFIG:Debug>, file_to_generate_in_debug, file_to_generate_in_release>
)
```

If some other target needs your configuration-dependent output file, then you may adjust target-level dependencies:

```
# Depends from the target which produces required file
add_dependencies(other_target MY_GEN_LIB)
```

This will work even if the other target is an *IMPORTED* one.